# How do you use Blazor in the scaffolded Identity pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity, blazor-server-side

Created a new Blazor server project with Identity and then scaffolded it. But the files are .cshtml. How do you go about using Blazor to for example do form validation on Register.cshtml?

Comment: Do you want to use Blazor for the (public facing) frontend (login page, confirmation etc)? Or just for the administrative panel to manage the users and stuff? I would highly recommend not to do that, since the login is supposed to run in places were you may not have wasm support (i.e. Internet Explorer, or in general the Html Components in applications, such as WPF or WinForms) unless you want to run blazor-server sided, but then you're probably better off with Razor pages/views for the public facing frontend. If its for administrative pages only, its okay to us it imho

Comment: On top of that, in order to set the cookie a browser redirection is required, blazor server-sided is basically ajax/websocket communication for the updates which don't by default allow cookies to be set (which is required for identity authentication)

Comment: @Tseng I meant public facing. So we are not done with Javascript yet? Im a beginner so I liked the possibility of being able to code in C# only to get more experience.

Comment: No. Blazor runs on wasm and there are still browsers which don't support it. Highly depends on your audience. For an intranet applications where you know all clients will support it and it will never be used from inside an WPF/WinForm site it may be viable. But imho its best not to change the existing templates too much and redirect the user (after login) to a specific page where the blazor spa starts rather than replacing the existing templates with blazor versions of it

Comment: only IE doesn't support it, but it's still in Preview (on wasm) until May.  Blazor Server is good to go right now.